# strange behaviour of css columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Anyone have idea, why when I using css columns it behave very strange? I mean i've got

```css
 ul{    
        columns: 4;
        column-gap: 100px;
        column-rule: 1px solid #eaeef6;
      }
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    </ul>
```

My expectation is to display it like that:

```
A|B|C|D|
E| | | |
```

But i've got that:

```
A|C|D| |
B| |E| |
```

Why? thanks

Comment: Try using Flexbox: Doing `ul { display: flex; flex-flow: wrap; column-gap: 100px; }` works.

Comment: That is the default behaviour. You wanted the layout to form text columns//which it does... *in that order* not rows - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: This works better with multiples of 4. Columns spec is strange, and implemented differently by Chrome than other browsers in small ways like how some styling overlaps columns (drop shadow).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use display: grid if that might help?

```
 ul{   
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
```

If you want it to wrap, you use media queries or flex ( flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap ) but then you would kinda lose the column aspect of your "table" if that is supposed to be one.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Aww this is it what i'm looking for. thans :D

Comment: @Czachovsky you can always accept an answer by selecting the checkmark by the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking to set your grid up like this?

```css
 ul{    
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
        column-gap: 100px;
        column-rule: 1px solid #eaeef6;
      }
```

```html
   <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: almost, but i have to display it from top to bottom, instad of from left to right

Comment: @Czachovsky Then I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Doesn't your provided code do exactly that?